# VS Code - How to open a file by its full path in the command palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need some functions like:

> VS Code -> F1 (open Command Palette) -> *OpenFileFeature*:
> /home/user/blablabla/code.py -> (Enter) -> (file opened in editor)

In this case */home/user/blablabla/code.py* can be an external file (relative to my current folder open in VS Code).

Does anyone know some tricks about this?

Comment: If you search the extensions for "open file" there's a huge number of hits; I'm sure one of these will meet your needs.

Comment: thanks!
So its seems like no in-build solutions? ok.
Should you use any of such extensions - can you recommend the best one of your experience?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use any, and recommendations are off-topic anyway.

Comment: How is this a bad question? It's a legitimate inquiry that new users may not know how to do @KenY-N . You don't need an extension for something that vscode natively supports. That's just silly in my opinion

Comment: "bad", perhaps not, but "low quality" by SO definition. It shows no research. Though tbf, when I started to "research" this was the first hit :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In vscode you can use the command palette to open files via absolute path using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> shortcut. Please note the difference. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> opens the file navigator whereas <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> opens the editor command window, meaning you will see the `>` indicator. Additional note - you could just simply delete the `>` identifier as well, if using the command shortcut.

The file navigator takes absolute paths as arguments, once you filled out a file that exists it will populate in the drop down list for selection:
[image: screenshot]

Notice how I do not have any workspaces open so there is no navigation history or relative file association.

---

Alternatively,

There is naturally the option to open via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, where you can always enter absolute paths as well, not a command palette related answer but related option.

Comment: thanks a lot!
looks like Ctrl+P -> (enter/paste full filename) works just perfect!
have a good day and so on:)

Comment: This only shows recently opened files for me no matter how I type the path.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to open file outside workspace in the current window:

1. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
2. Type `code [any_file_path]`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I don't know why someone else downvoted this, but I can assure you it doesn't open the file in the "current" window. I have two Code sessions open. I was trying to copy a file from one project to another. When I use your method in the destination project's Terminal, it opened the file in the Source project's instance!

Comment: That is how VS Code works - if the file is part of opened editor - it will open there to prevent duplicates.

Comment: That's neither here nor there (though it really shouldn't care if there are duplicates -- most editors are entirely capable of having multiple copies open, _including_ VS Code). The point is that it will not necessarily open in the current window.

Comment: @Auspex Do you know if there is a setting I can set to open all files even those, that are not in the project/workspace

Comment: Not sure why you'd ask me -- it's not my answer! If you use _this_ method with a directory path, rather than a file, it will open a completely new instance of Code (with all the files in that directory)

Answer (score -2):

I tried the accepted answer and it did not work for me. I'm on OSX. After pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, when I start typing absolute path of a file, it simply shows `No matching results`.

What worked for me was opening file from the file navigator. Go to `File > Open` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) and locate the file in the file browser. It opens the file in same window in a tab.